# SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

I am using Facebook login in android.
**Code:**

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) this.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "FB", "inicio session ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "FB", "OP NO completada");
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "FB", " Errro de sesion ");
            exception.printStackTrace();
            // App code
        }
    });
```

but always getting the following error:

> SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query.
>   [extra]: Errors while executing operation "ProxyAuthAppLoginQuery": At
>   Query.proxy_auth_app_login: Failed to resolve field. W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:190)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:159)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.procibernetica.moca.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:130)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3401)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3448)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
>   W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I've added the folowing permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: i have the same problem, answer your question your self  if you found any solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems that the problem is with facebook itself..

Comment: Try re-checking your Facebook APP ID

Comment: None of these solutions fixed my problem :(

Comment: ummm is bad solution, but if you delete and recreate the app in Facebook console?

Comment: As a comment said at bottom on login you should add the basic app permissions "email", "public_profile", "user_friends"

Comment: If I add the above three permissions and not enabled the user_friends permission in the developer console. Does it make any issues?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I find the solution, this happends when you don't have evaluate users in your app .

Enter in your panel App
Select Rol

[image]

And add test users , when your try to login with test users , the application executes without fails

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason for needing to do this is because your app is in "development mode" (see the setting for this located on the "App Review" panel).  Development mode apps are considered private and can only be used by specifically-authorized users.  Making the app public removes this restriction, so is an alternative to listing the users you want to have access.

Comment: This is not working in my case , but getting same exception. can u help?
I've added tester now login with tester account. still same exception

Comment: Another solution is set app as public , follow the response of @AMAN SINGH , and refresh tokens

Comment: I have my app published, yet i'm seeing the same error. Also I double checked to make sure my App ID is correct

Comment: I feel like this error is happening for me because I owe Facebook money from previous advertisements.

Comment: @Gabriel did you manage to solve the issue? I'm presenting the same problem. I have our app published and yet this still happens.

Comment: did anyone get the solution to issue

Comment: For me the `LoginManager.getInstance().loginBehavior` was default to `NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK` changing to `WEB_VIEW_ONLY` Fixed it

Comment: Yes, this step is important especially if you are in development mode.

Answer (score 63):

Documentation on facebook is not correct. I had to add all 3 default permissions to make it work.

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_friends");
```

Comment: Thanks man, this solution works for me the solution marked as correct above does not work. I do not if this is related with  use a custom login, facebook, meaning in my app I changed the fbk login button for an android button. nevermind it works

Comment: Works for me too but makes me wonder if all three read permissions are needed, why does the Facebook official documentation only mention "email" permission ?

Comment: Thanks it worked for me after I omitted the `user_friends`

Comment: @liorko your comment is contradictory, you are thanking and saying that you omitted user_friends, please clarify

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain it's worked for me with this line:`loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")`

Comment: As of 2018 anyway, the FB app has email and public_profile read permissions set by default, so no need to set them again.

Comment: I had "email" and "public_profile" set as permissions and it worked on the emulators. To make it work on my real device, I needed to add also "user_friends".

Comment: @stefita I have set user_friends in code and I don't need that permission. So If I add the permission and not enabled the user_friends make any issues while going to app review
My app's login loaded with two permissions, after adding the above three permissions it worked

Answer (score 23):

@Danial answer correct, But I want to add some more in that. This types of error comes only when app your in under development. Follow this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and select your App. Then you can do two things here. From **Roles** tab you can allow login to your friends only or else select the **App Review** and make your `app public` then any one can able to logged in.

Answer (score 16):

I was getting a similar issue because Firebase UI was specifying the `android:value`. This is how I solved it:

```
    <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
<acitivity
...
</activity>
...
```

Comment: This is what fixed this issue for me. It seems to be lacking in the documentation.

Comment: This is the fix for apps that have the FirebaseUI dependency. When trying to compile the app an error message will be displayed suggesting this solution.

Comment: Where does "tools:replace" come from please ?

Comment: Where can i read more about this ?

Answer (score 14):

> Issue Log: **SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query**

And **Accurate Solution** for this Specific issue (**Error performing query**) 

is answered by **@aloha** is by updating the query for access.

loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_friends");

1. Find where you facebook login button was called.
2. Then set the ReadPermission for the button as **"email", "public_profile", "user_friends"**

**image Reference**

[image]

> Issue Log: **App Not Setup. This app is still in development mode. and you dont have access to it. register test user or ask an app admin for permission**

1. The app are not in Live Mode
2. You are not listed as admin or a tester in 
   https://developers.facebook.com/app/yourapp
3. Your App Hashkey are not set. if Facebook app cant be on Live Mode you need a hashkey to test it. because the app are not yet Live. Facebook wont allow an access.

**HOW TO CHANGE TO LIVE MODE**
 1. go to : https://developers.facebook.com
 2. select your app on "**My Apps**" List
 3. toggle the switch from OFF to ON

[image][image]

**HOW TO ADD AS TEST OR ADMIN**
 1. go to : https://developers.facebook.com
 2. select your app on "**My Apps**" List
 3. go to : Roles > Roles > Press Add for example administrator[image]
 4. Search your new admin/tester Facebook account.
[image]
 5. admin must enter facebook password to confirm.then submit
[image]

**the new admin must go to developer.facebook page and accept the request**
 6. go to : https://developers.facebook.com
 
 7. Profile > Requests > Confirm
 [image]
 [image: List item]
 8. **Congratulation** you have been assign as new Admin

**HOW TO GET AND SET HASHKEY FOR DEVELOPMENT**
as Refer to Facebook Login Documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#create_hash

The most preferable solution by me is by code ( **Troubleshooting Sample Apps** )

it will print out the hash key. you can update it on

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/yourFacebookappID/settings/basic/ 
on **Android > Key Hashes** section

**a step by step process on how to get the hashKey.**

1. Firstly Add the code to any oncreate method

   [image]
2. Run The app and Search the KeyHash at Logcat

   [image]

**step by step process on how Update on Facebook Developer.**

3. Open Facebook Developer Page. You need access as to update the Facebook Developer page: https://developers.facebook.com
4. Follow the step as follow.

   [image]

Comment: So all three permissions need to be enabled in the app review of the Facebook developer account as well? Am I correct? 1. My app loading and shows the error performing query. After adding the email and user_friends, public_profile it shows the app not setup error in the UI.

Does this will be fixed after reappealing the app?

Answer (score 12):

All of the above answers didn't help me, what did was when you use this command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

to get the Key Hashes you put in facebook configurations.

it will ask you for a password, at first I didn't set any, so the issue happened, when I entered `android` as the password. it worked !

Comment: This solved it for me ! I had already changed the app id from strings.xml, and did many other suggested answers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

[Live developer mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swryu.png)
Please check status of Developer mode. It must be "Live".
Firstly, you need add privacy url for own facebook project which you want to test facebook login or sth .... Then enable developer mode (Turn on)

Answer (score 5):

I just fixed it by going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
and select my app then

**`switch to live mode`**

"from top left beside app ID"

Comment: My app not able to switch, it shows the message as "You may not make your app available to all users"

Answer (score 4):

In my case the generated hash key was wrong because i was using wrong OpenSSL.
I was using openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip instead of openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip and this generated me a wrong hash key which caused this problem hope it helps some one i lost like 8 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was wrong generated Key Hash which need to submit on facebook app page
Solution found on this article https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/advanced

**Manually Check Key Hash** - You can print out the key hash sent to Facebook and use that value in App Dashboard. Make this change to *onCreate()* in your main activity:

```
try 
{
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                        "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto",
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {  


} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {  

}
```

Answer (score 3):

for Flutter this was the fix

```
final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(
      permissions: [
        'public_profile',
        'email',
        'pages_show_list',
        'pages_messaging',
        'pages_manage_metadata'
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it's sad that flutter_facebook_auth[https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth] plugin does NOT state that in the docs!

Answer (score 2):

This error is returned in other situations too - even when your app is public or you're listed as a tester.

Double check that your

`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`

is resolving to a correct Facebook App ID, especially if you dynamically specify it using gradle build, rather than hard coding it in strings.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I addition to the other answers please also check that the email of the account being used to log in is verified.

Answer (score 2):

you need to see if the user that connect in the phone facebook app is a user that have test or developer permissions in the facebook developers on the app page.

Answer (score 1):

Add a string resource "facebook_application_id" in your strings.xml

replace APP_ID with your facebook app id

```
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">APP_ID</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added this line and it worked for me.

```
facebookLogin.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_friends");
```

Comment: Shall I need to enable all the  above permissons facebook developer account? Or does it enable automatically?

Comment: In my account, it only have the public_profile and email as its permission. But if i use this it shows unspported request. Are you sure, shall I need to enable all the above three permissions for sure?

Comment: You can try to enable all the above permissions on developer account may be work for you.

Comment: If I not enable the above three and add only two permissions does it work?

Comment: I am getting Something went wrong error UI

Comment: post full error.

Comment: its same as unsupported request error

Comment: I have a clarification, If I add the above three permissions in the code and not enabled the user_friends option in the developer account, my app not get loading. Does this make any issue while going to the app review

Answer (score 1):

try this, locate your app-debug.apk in android build folder

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

paste it in facebook key hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but from personal experience when you generate the development key you will need to type a password which is "android" and make sure you add the = after the code when you are adding it in the field on developers facebook domain