# Android release Facebook login failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am using Facebook login in my android App, and everything worked fine in the debug mode. However, when I published it on Google Play and my friends downloaded it, Facebook login failed, showing this message:

> SERVER_ERROR:[code]1675030[message]:Error performing query. [extra]: Errors while executing operation "ProxyAuthAppLoginQuery": At Query.proxy_auth_app_login: Failed to resolve field.

I had added both the DEBUG and RELEASE hash keys already in developers.facebook.com. before I published the App, but login still failed. Where did things go wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried with this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41895234/2910520

Comment: I had followed this when my app was in "development mode" and everything worked fine. But now I have released the App and login failed as mentioned above.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @Einsambr I also published my app yet I'm seeing the same error

Comment: Any update guys?

Comment: Not yet... still the same

Comment: Sane here, can't find the issue.

Comment: did u set a app to public mode in fb dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that on the facebook dev console, the app is public, the app ids match the one's in the app and all keys are set. Details regarding that can be found in this thread.

[SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861564/server-error-code-1675030-message-error-performing-query/43962912#43962912)

If the issue still remains.

Make sure the account being used to log in should have a verified email address. If still not working (old emails on facebook weren't verified) and not sure if the email is verified or not, add a new verified email to the facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved this adding the three basic facebook app permissions to the login process email, user_profile, phone_number.
you can add those permissions to the login button, or your on login flow.

```
     loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_friends");
```

or if you have a custom login flow, with custom button just something like

```
        List<String> permission =
            new ArrayList<>();
    permission.add("email");
    permission.add("public_profile");
    permission.add("user_friends");
    LoginManager.getInstance()
            .setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK)
            .logInWithReadPermissions(activity,
                    permission);
```