# Facebook login with android sdk not working

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have integrated **Facebook** login to my android application. It used to work. But now it's not working. When I debugged the application I found that now **LoginManager Callback** is giving an Exception. I don't know what this is, and how to solve it.
And this is the exception I got

> exception: "SERVER_ERROR [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing
>   query. [extra]: Errors while executing operation
>   "ProxyAuthAppLoginStartQuery": At Query.proxy_auth_app_login_start:
>   Failed to resolve field."

**code**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, null);
    CardView mSignInFbButton = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_fb);
    mSignInFbButton.setOnClickListener(v ->{
                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                }
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SignInFragment.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
            }
    );
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, mFBSignInCallback);
    return view;
}

private FacebookCallback mFBSignInCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Beco.getApp().currentUser().signInFacebook();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onError");
    }
};
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

In the **LoginManager Callback** it's going to `public void onError(FacebookException exception)`
 All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/649 its an issue from facebook side. Kindly check this.

Comment: Also check with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895234/2556660

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open your registered app in Facebook developer console.

This method will make app publicly available for all testing devices:

1. Select 'App Review' option
2. Make Social Adds public? enable it to 'Yes'

OR

This method will let you test app on selected devices:

1. Select 'Role' option
2. Add 'Testers' for application

Answer (score 1):

this appends when you don't have evaluate users in your app.

[image]

And add test users , when your try to login with test users , the app excuse without fails.

[Here is google groups answers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-stackoverflow/yiAyHirju_8)

But I think you should use callbackManager at onCreate.
        Below is sample code for Facebook signIn integration

```
        public class SignInFragment extends Fragment{   
         @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                }
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, null);

          LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, mFBSignInCallback);

         List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SignInFragment.this, permissionNeeds);

             return view;
            }

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFBSignInCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "in LoginResult on success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("VIVZ", "onCancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        Log.d("VIVZ", "onError " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                };

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

        }
```