# why facebook login raise Error performing query

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I have implemented Facebook login on my android app,using *development* key hash, and I don't use fire-base, and I am getting the following run-time error when I click on the facebook login button loginButton:

> SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query.
>   [extra]: null

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

minSdkVersion 19

targetSdkVersion 21

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.36.0'

LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook sign in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code                
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

even i am testing Facebook login using a a tester user, which i defined in Facebook developer Roles.

if added "user_friends" to the read permissions facebook login crash:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile","user_friends");
```

[facebook login crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MK7H.png)

but if i didn't include "user_friends",  i reach the following stage, but when click continue, i got error "error in performing query: extra: null" as described above:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
```

[facebook login dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIztK.png)

so can anybody advise please?

thank you

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861564/server-error-code-1675030-message-error-performing-query

Comment: thank you, but i tried to test my app using a facebook tester account (i defined in facebook Roles), but it still give me the same error, so i am wondering is it becuase i dont use fire-base? i mean is it necessary to register in fire-base to use facebook login on android app?

Comment: No its not , you dont have to use firebase compulsory