# Facebook login sdk - Android

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to connect on my app with the facebook login. I did all these [steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/) and I am facing a strange issue.
So the login button works because the facebook login window appears but I am not getting the facebook token (onError is called).

I already tried all the solutions from this [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861564/server-error-code-1675030-message-error-performing-query).

This code is the same as the one in the Facebook tutorial.

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

This is my error which is a bit different from the [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861564/server-error-code-1675030-message-error-performing-query) (extra: null):

```
09-12 21:13:40.317 29573-29573/com.xxxx.yyyy D/FACEBOOK: facebook:onError
SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query. [extra]: null
    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:219)
    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:174)
    at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:92)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In my Build.gradle I added the Facebook SDK

```
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
```

Activity:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private static final String TAG = "FACEBOOK";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

}

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));`

Comment: I tried and didnt work...

Comment: Are you on the debug build by any chance?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @carton Make sure your app is Public mode.https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057022/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes she is in Public mode.

Answer (score 2):

Two things should be done to avoid these problems.

1. This samples of error come only when an app you are in under development. Follow this **[link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)** and select your App. Then you can do two things here. From Roles tab, you can allow login to your friends only or else select the App Review and make your app public then anyone can able to log in. And also Refresh Your Tokens.

Go to your panel and select Admin Portal.
[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvKW0.png)
and Add tester to your Project.[Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk0VX.png)

**And also**

**Incorrect**

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```

**Correct one is**

`loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_friends");`

Comment: Like i said i already tried this way to set permissions and to add test users with my second facebook account. Nothing change.

Comment: Ok, Have you checked the status of Developer mode. It must be "Live".

Comment: Firstly, you need to add privacy URL for own facebook project which you want to test facebook login. Then enable developer mode (Turn on).

Comment: Use this command to get the Key Hashes you put in facebook configurations.        
  [  keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64  ]                                                                .It will enquire you for a password,firstly I didn't set any, so the issue happened, when I entered android as the password.

Comment: I already put a keyhash. If you don't facebook is telling you before my error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by the status of the application in [Facebook Developer Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) is under development !

To go live add the privacy policy URL in the Basic settings and Click on Save Changes

**EDIT:** Change your dependency to

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
```

And create Application class as below

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
}
```

don't forget declare its in manifest `android:name=".MyApplication"`

Comment: the status should show **live** if you still getting error post manifest file

Comment: The status is "live" and still not working. i edited the post to show you the manifest, but i think the problem isn't located in manifest.

Comment: ok i need also see full code in activity class with build.gradle files

Comment: I added what you need.

Comment: Nothing change, i already saw and tried this solution and it didn't work. + sdkInitialize is deprecated.