# Facebook Login in Android show error preforming query

Tags: java, android, facebook

I implement Facebook login in Android but when i click on continue with Facebook it show the popup to continue with my Facebook account it show `SERVER_ERROR :[code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query [extra]: null`
i already add test account in Roles section in Facebook app page
any help?

Comment: Have you found the solution ? i have the same problem and already asked this question there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302109/facebook-login-sdk-android

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app is public and it's asking for valid information about user. Like the the parameters (ex: `email`, `user_friends`) you are passing has read permission.

Comment: Make sure that your `android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"` is generated properly.

Comment: also i did that same issue i try to log in with the test user that given from facebook its not showing this error but it show the hash is wrong