# Unable to Integrating facebook login in android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've integrated facebook login in my android app. I've followed all the instructions in graph API, but I'm unable to log in using Facebook. Following error is coming when I try to log in.

```
E/LoginActivity: Facebook Sign In ErrorSERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query. [extra]:   
 2018-12-21 10:53:54.793 22070-24918/? E/fb4a.GraphServiceQueryExecutor: query error
    X.61v: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query. [extra]: 
        at X.1aK.onError(:267992)
        at com.facebook.common.jniexecutors.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.common.jniexecutors.PooledNativeRunnable.run(:73274)
        at X.0gf.execute(:60937)
        at com.facebook.common.jniexecutors.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.common.jniexecutors.PooledNativeRunnable.run(:73274)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at X.1l6.run(:117601)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at X.1lJ.run(:117620)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I've tried every solution in google and StackOverflow.
Please, anyone, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Facebook Developer account you are using is verified by email. I had the same issue, I was using Facebook account which was not verified by email. Issue resolved for me now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're struggling with this, you can find the right answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895234/6663777

You either need to have a tester account or to publish the app on Facebook dashboard.